# Link content inside div ignoring margins

Tags: html, css

I'm setting margin-left and right to auto in order to center a div.

```
<a>

 <div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:32px; height:32px">

 </div>

</a>
```

How can I make the 32x32 content to be the only linked zone (ignoring the margins)?

Thanks!

Comment: You can't. Anything **inside** the anchor will be part of the link. You might have to rethink your HTML structure.

Comment: use `div > a` instead of `a > div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div style="margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:32px; height:32px; ">
<a href="#">
link
</a>
</div>
```

Simply turn it inside out :)

Another way is to make your link block, and no need in divs:

```
<a href="#" style="display:block;margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto; width:32px; height:32px; ">
   link
</a>
```

Comment: @cerealex if answer worked, tap the checkmark below vote count of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this

```
 <div style="text-align: center">
   <a style="display: inline-block; width:32px; height:32px" >sdf</a>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`A` is a inline tag. `div` is a block tag. Either try to place div out of a (valid syntax for < HTML5) or make your `a` block tag.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML :**

```
<div style="text-align: center; margin: 0px auto;">
   <a style="display: inline-block; width:32px; height:32px" >sdf</a>
 </div>
```